# files cannot be read after WINDEV mobile upload using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, windev

I am trying to use the graph api upload feature (in my case it is using Windev Mobile 21).

The files are appearing in the appfolder.  They are the right size and have the right extensions but they can not be opened

```
sCd1 is ANSI string = "Authorization: Bearer"+" "+gsTokenAcc

HTTPCreateForm("driveEnq")
sContentType is ANSI string = "image/jpeg"
HTTPAddFile("driveEnq","File",sAd,sContentType)=False

sEnding is ANSI string 
sHTTPRes is string
sUserAgent is ANSI string = "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393'"

IF HTTPSendForm("driveEnq",sEnding,httpPut,sUserAgent ,sCd1)=True THEN
bufResHTTP is Buffer = HTTPGetResult(httpResult)
```

I am convinced that this is something to do with the content type or the format by which the files are added

Answer (score 0):

The key to this appears to be to add the file (or fragment) via an empty

```
HTTPAddParameter("form_name","",sFrag)
```

Adding the form as a application/XML appears to help with the boundaries of each field.

Hope this helps